# I am trying to create a lexicon using an input file in C++

Tags: c++, lexicon

I have a file.txt I want to create a function in C++ that can read the words in that file, and print each word and how many times they occur into a file2.txt

I am doing some research I know i can use the parser and writer, and also the map class, any help please?

```
bool Parser::hasMoreTokens() {
  if(source.peek()!=NULL){
    return true;
}
else{
     return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Step 1: *You* provide some code first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this home work? Look online for `std::map`, `std:string`, `std::ifstream` and `std::ofstream`.

Answer (score 1):

Read the file using [ifstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/), store into [map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/) of [string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)s, use `int` as value of `map` and increment that each time you encounter a specific `string`. Next, write them to file using [ofstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ofstream/).

Comment: i need help implementing the parser function

Comment: what does your parser funcion do?

Comment: it is a parser class that i have to implment, i want to make the parse class able to handle the Input operations

Comment: do i use the ifstream to read from the file, i wrote source.open(filename);

Comment: so i have functions in the parser.cpp that i have to implement

Comment: Parser::Parser(string filename) the constructor

Comment: Parser::~Parser() //destructor
bool Parser::hasMoreTokens() //if there are any more tokens
string Parser::nextToken() { //the next token
void Parser::close() { //close the aprser

Comment: @user570098 : The point you seem to be oblivious to is that no one here is going to do your homework for you. The best you can ask for is to be told what to search for and read up on, which has been done sufficiently.

Comment: i understand that, i just need to find out where i can find this information

Comment: @user570098, enough information is already given. don't you think that?

Comment: also, google can show you enough tutorial. for example: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be efficient and accomplish this in less possible amount of lines, but by using standard library, try this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <set>
#include <string>

int main()
{
     std::ifstream f("text.txt");
     std::istream_iterator<std::string> eof;
     std::multiset<std::string> words( std::istream_iterator<std::string>(f) , eof);

     std::ofstream f_out("text_output.txt");
     for( std::multiset<std::string>::iterator i = words.begin(); i!=words.end(); i = words.upper_bound(*i) )
          f_out << "the word " << *i << " found " << words.count(*i) << " times\n";

}
```

This code grabs the file named "text.txt" and outputs result to "text_output.txt"

- Contents of "text.txt":
  can can can I I I do this properly?
  How many times do I need to program one thing to remember it?
- Contents of "text_output.txt":
  the word How found 1 times
  the word I found 4 times
  the word can found 3 times
  the word do found 2 times
  the word it? found 1 times
  the word many found 1 times
  the word need found 1 times
  the word one found 1 times
  the word program found 1 times
  the word properly? found 1 times
  the word remember found 1 times
  the word thing found 1 times
  the word this found 1 times
  the word times found 1 times
  the word to found 2 times

Good resource to learn fantastic ways of using c++ efficiently is a book called Accelerated c++.

Regards,